# Use if-let for more than one condition

Tags: swift

I have a code that looks like so:

```
   let myItems = presenter?.getShoppingListItems()
    if myFlag.isEnabled() && myItems!.isEmpty {
        //Do something
```

Now, I want to write this line `if myFlag.isEnabled() && shoppingListItems!.isEmpty` using `if-let`.

I tried this:

```
  let myItems = presenter?.getShoppingListItems()
        if let _ = myFlag.isEnabled(), let myItems = myItems?.isEmpty {
            //Do something
```

And this:

```
    let myItems = presenter?.getShoppingListItems()
        if let myFlag.isEnabled(), let _ = myItems?.isEmpty {
        //Do something
```

But it's not working. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you want to use `if let`? I'm guessing you want to remove the use of the force unwrapping? If so, do you want the if statement to run or not when `myItems` is nil?

Comment: Yes..I want to remove the force unwrapping..@Sweeper

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
if let items = presenter?.getShoppingListItems(), items.isEmpty, myFlag.isEnabled() { ... }
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.

Answer (score 3):

Optional binding (`if let ...`) is supposed to be used when you want to unwrap an optional value and bind it to an identifier. Here, you are not trying to bind anything - you are just trying to check two conditions: `myFlag.isEnabled()` and `myItems?.isEmpty`, so a regular if condition will work.

You *do* need to make sure that the conditions are of type `Bool` though, not `Bool?`.

Assuming yo do not want the if statement to run when `myItems` is nil, you can achieve this by directly comparing the optional `myItems?.isEmpty` with `true`.

```
if myFlag.isEnabled() && myItems?.isEmpty == true {
```

Alternatively, you can mix optional binding with regular `Bool` conditions. You can bind `myItems`, and check `isEnabled` and `isEmpty`, all within the same if statement:

```
if let myItems = presenter?.getShoppingListItems(),
    myFlag.isEnabled(), myItems.isEmpty == true {

}
```

Or you can bind on `myItems?.isEmpty`, since that is an optional as well:

```
if let isEmpty = myItems?.isEmpty,
    myFlag.isEnabled(), isEmpty {

}
```

---

If you want the if statement to also be executed when `myItems` is nil, you can change the condition to `!= false`:

```
if myFlag.isEnabled() && myItems?.isEmpty != false {
```